# Variables not recieving the values they are intended to

Tags: c

I have came across a problem that while reading from a file, I couldn't give my variables a proper value.
I have used a similar approach at a previous project, the only difference is that there I was only supposed to store the height and width of a matrix, and now I also have to store an additional line before I can store the height and width values.

Code:

```
int fromMountain = 0, fromWater = 0, fromSand = 0, height = 0, width = 0;
char **terrain;

void readFiles() {
    inFile = fopen("be.txt", "r");
    outFile = fopen("ki.txt", "w");
}

void storeData() {
    fscanf(inFile, "%d %d %d\n", &fromMountain, &fromWater, &fromSand);
    fscanf(inFile, "%d %d\n", &height, &width);
    terrain = (char**)malloc(height*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile, "%c", &terrain[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void testPrint() {
    printf("%d %d %d\n", fromMountain, fromWater, fromSand);
    printf("%d %d\n", height, width);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%c", terrain[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Code doesn't seem to run properly, there is no output.
```

Source file:

```
1 2 2
10 10
~00000000A
00000000AA
00~~~A00XX
000~0A0000
000000000~
A00000000~
000000000~
0000~00000
00000X0000
0A0A000AAA
```

I have tried changing things up a bit and make my integer variables char type.
That didn't seem to help anything, nothing has changed. Output was still non-existent and I got nowhere closer to a proper solution.

Any form of help is appreciated! :)

Comment: you allocate memory for a single `char**`, but don't allocate actual memory for the cells.

Comment: Ohh, that pretty much slipped out of my attention! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here's the thing, anyone looking for something similar.

It is not enough to allocate memory for your variable, `**terrain` in this case, you also have to allocate a piece of memory for the data you would like to store.

After allocating memory for the variable itself, you will need another piece of code, something similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    terrain[i] = (char*)malloc(width * sizeof(char));
}
```

Thanks for Raildex for pointing it out!